# Allwinner a64 - switch from aarch32 to aarch64 by warm reset

Tags: u-boot, arm64, bare-metal

I want to deploy a simple bare metal software on the Pine64 board, hosting Allwinner A64 SoC. The configuration is following: when powered on, **boot0** starts u-boot, which loads my `hello.bin` to RAM (`0x40000000`) and starts executing it. The thing is that it is in aarch32 execution state and I want aarch64.

I have found out a way how to do it as in [this patch](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/include/asm/arch-sunxi/boot0.h;hb=HEAD). Some background also [on the wiki](http://linux-sunxi.org/Arm64).

I have copied the code and the `objdump -d hello.o` returns identical results as in the link:

Disassembly of section .text:

```
00000000 <_reset>:
   0:   e59f0024        ldr     r0, [pc, #36]   ; 2c <_reset+0x2c>
   4:   e59f1024        ldr     r1, [pc, #36]   ; 30 <_reset+0x30>
   8:   e5801000        str     r1, [r0]
   c:   f57ff04f        dsb     sy
  10:   f57ff06f        isb     sy
  14:   ee1c0f50        mrc     15, 0, r0, cr12, cr0, {2}
  18:   e3800003        orr     r0, r0, #3
  1c:   ee0c0f50        mcr     15, 0, r0, cr12, cr0, {2}
  20:   f57ff06f        isb     sy
  24:   e320f003        wfi
  28:   eafffffe        b       28 <_reset+0x28>
  2c:   017000a0        .word   0x017000a0
  30:   40008000        .word   0x40008000
```

It is supposed to perform a **warm-reset** and start executin at `0x40008000` in aarch64 execution state. But when running I am getting **Undefined instruction** error and it restarts in the same state and starts from `0x0`.

```
## Starting application at 0x40000000 ...                    
undefined instruction                                        
pc : [<40000018>]          lr : [<7ff1d054>]                 
sp : 76eb8a90  ip : 00000030     fp : 7ff1d00c               
r10: 00000002  r9 : 76ed0ea0     r8 : 7ffb5340               
r7 : 77f1bd78  r6 : 40000000     r5 : 00000002  r4 : 77f1bd7c
r3 : 40000000  r2 : 77f1bd7c     r1 : 40008000  r0 : 017000a0
Flags: nZCv  IRQs on  FIQs off  Mode SVC_32                  
Resetting CPU ...
```

Why is that?

EDIT:

1. The first problem was noticed by @Frant below, the binary that should be linked with different .text section address, that is start from `0x40000000` instead of `0x0`.
2. It also couldn't work loaded by u-boot, that is in EL2. In order to write to RMR one needs to be in EL3. This is possible with FEL method.

NOTE:
After facing this problem I was asking around for some help and apparently I was using an old way of flashing the board. Since some time Pine64 got much better support and now it is possible to boot it in two more convenient ways:
* mainline u-boot with atf, that will directly generate a binary one can flash to SD card, and drops you in EL2,
* using the `sunxi-fel` tool, as described below, which is very convenient if one does not want to re-flash SD card all the time, drops you in EL3 (WARNING: sunxi wiki is a bit misleading on the `sunxi-fel` command arguments, these one below worked for me).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer is an attempt to answer the following question: Does the aarch32 state-switching code you are using work ?
 The good new is that the code you are using works fine. The bad new is that something else may not work properly in your environment.This would not surprise me much given the terrible state of all Allwinner out-of-the box BSPs.
Since I did not know which exact versions of boot0 and u-boot you were using, I tested your code using Andre Przywara's [FEL-capable SPL binaries](https://github.com/apritzel/pine64/tree/master/binaries) for A64/H5 - see the [FEL Booting](http://linux-sunxi.org/A64#FEL_booting) section of the A64 entry for more details - and [sunxi-fel](http://linux-sunxi.org/FEL#Running_the_sunxi-fel_tool):This does remove the boot0 and u-boot you are using as potential  culprits.
The [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I built for testing your code requires:

- Removing the SD card from the Pine64, so that it will enter the FEL mode at power-up,
- A male-A to male-A USB 2.0 cable for connecting your PC to the [upper USB host receptacle](http://linux-sunxi.org/Pine64#FEL_mode) of the Pine64.
- A bash script, `build.sh`, for building sunxi-tools, retrieving the FEL-capable SPL binaries,
- `rmr_switch.S`, a version of [rmr_switch.S](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/arch/arm/mach-sunxi/rmr_switch.S) minus comments plus a symbol to be pre-processed for setting the start address without having to modify the file all the time,
- `rmr_switch2.S`, a version of the rmr_switch.S mentionned above, but using r0 and r1 the way they are being used in the patch you were referencing.
- `uart-aarch32.s`, an aarch32 program displaying `*** Hello from aarch32! ***` on UART0,
- `uart-aarch64.s`, an aarch64 program displaying `*** Hello from aarch64! ***` on UART0.

  Here is the content for each of the required files:
- build.sh:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  # usage: 
  # CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH64=/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_aarch64-elf/bin/aarch64-elf- CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32=/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-eabi/bin/arm-eabi- ./build.sh

  clear

  CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH64=${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH64:-/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_aarch64-elf/bin/aarch64-elf-}
  CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32=${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32:-/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-eabi/bin/arm-eabi-}
  SOC=${SOC:-a64}

  #AARCH32_START_ADDRESS=0x42000000
  #AARCH64_START_ADDRESS=0x42010000

  AARCH32_START_ADDRESS=0x40000000 
  AARCH64_START_ADDRESS=0x40008000

  SUNXI_FEL=sunxi-tools/sunxi-fel

  install_sunxi_tools()
  {
    if [ ! -f ${SUNXI_FEL} ]
    then
      git clone --branch v1.4.2 https://github.com/linux-sunxi/sunxi-tools
      pushd sunxi-tools
      make 
      popd
    fi
  }

  retrieve_spl_aarch32()
  {
    if [ ! -f sunxi-a64-spl32-ddr3.bin ]
    then
      wget https://github.com/apritzel/pine64/raw/master/binaries/sunxi-a64-spl32-ddr3.bin
    fi

    if [ ! -f sunxi-h5-spl32-ddr3.bin ]
    then
      wget https://github.com/apritzel/pine64/raw/master/binaries/sunxi-h5-spl32-ddr3.bin
    fi
  }


  test_aarch32()
  {
    # testing aarch32 program
    PROGRAM=uart-aarch32.s
    BASE=${PROGRAM%%.*}

    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}gcc -O0 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -e ${AARCH64_START_ADDRESS} -Wl,-Ttext=${AARCH32_START_ADDRESS} -o ${BASE}.elf ${BASE}.s
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}objcopy --remove-section .note.gnu.build-id ${BASE}.elf
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}objcopy --remove-section .ARM.attributes ${BASE}.elf
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}objdump -D ${BASE}.elf > ${BASE}.lst
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}objcopy -O binary ${BASE}.elf  ${BASE}.bin
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}objcopy  ${BASE}.elf -O srec ${BASE}.srec

    echo "------------------ test uart-aarch32 -----------------------------"
    echo sudo ${SUNXI_FEL} spl sunxi-${SOC}-spl32-ddr3.bin
    echo sudo ${SUNXI_FEL} write ${AARCH32_START_ADDRESS} uart-aarch32.bin
    echo sudo ${SUNXI_FEL} exe ${AARCH32_START_ADDRESS}
    echo "------------------------------------------------------------------"
  }

  test_aarch64()
  {
    # testing aarch64 program
    PROGRAM=uart-aarch64.s
    BASE=${PROGRAM%%.*}

    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH64}gcc -O0 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -e ${AARCH64_START_ADDRESS} -Wl,-Ttext=${AARCH64_START_ADDRESS} -o ${BASE}.elf ${BASE}.s
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH64}objcopy --remove-section .note.gnu.build-id ${BASE}.elf
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH64}objcopy --remove-section .ARM.attributes ${BASE}.elf
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH64}objdump -D ${BASE}.elf > ${BASE}.lst
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH64}objcopy -O binary ${BASE}.elf  ${BASE}.bin
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH64}objcopy  ${BASE}.elf -O srec ${BASE}.srec

    echo "------------------ test uart-aarch64 -----------------------------"
    echo sudo ${SUNXI_FEL} spl sunxi-${SOC}-spl32-ddr3.bin
    echo sudo ${SUNXI_FEL} write ${AARCH64_START_ADDRESS} uart-aarch64.bin
    echo sudo ${SUNXI_FEL} reset64 ${AARCH64_START_ADDRESS}
    echo "------------------------------------------------------------------"
  }

  test_rmr_switch()
  {
  # compiling rmr_switch.s
    PROGRAM=rmr_switch.s
    BASE=${PROGRAM%%.*}

    rm -f ${BASE}.s
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH64}cpp -DAARCH64_START_ADDRESS=${AARCH64_START_ADDRESS} ${BASE}.S > ${BASE}.s

    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}gcc -O0 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -e ${AARCH32_START_ADDRESS} -Wl,-Ttext=${AARCH32_START_ADDRESS} -o ${BASE}.elf ${BASE}.s
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}objcopy --remove-section .note.gnu.build-id ${BASE}.elf
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}objcopy --remove-section .ARM.attributes ${BASE}.elf
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}objdump -D ${BASE}.elf > ${BASE}.lst
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}objcopy -O binary ${BASE}.elf  ${BASE}.bin
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}objcopy  ${BASE}.elf -O srec ${BASE}.srec

    echo "------------------ test rmr_switch uart-aarch64 ------------------"
    echo sudo ${SUNXI_FEL} spl sunxi-${SOC}-spl32-ddr3.bin
    echo sudo ${SUNXI_FEL} write ${AARCH32_START_ADDRESS} rmr_switch.bin
    echo sudo ${SUNXI_FEL} write ${AARCH64_START_ADDRESS} uart-aarch64.bin
    echo sudo ${SUNXI_FEL} exe ${AARCH32_START_ADDRESS}
    echo "------------------------------------------------------------------"
  }

  test_rmr_switch2()
  {
  # compiling rmr_switch2.s
    PROGRAM=rmr_switch2.s
    BASE=${PROGRAM%%.*}

    rm -f ${BASE}.s
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH64}cpp -DAARCH64_START_ADDRESS=${AARCH64_START_ADDRESS} ${BASE}.S > ${BASE}.s

    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}gcc -O0 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -e ${AARCH32_START_ADDRESS} -Wl,-Ttext=${AARCH32_START_ADDRESS} -o ${BASE}.elf ${BASE}.s
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}objcopy --remove-section .note.gnu.build-id ${BASE}.elf
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}objcopy --remove-section .ARM.attributes ${BASE}.elf
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}objdump -D ${BASE}.elf > ${BASE}.lst
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}objcopy -O binary ${BASE}.elf  ${BASE}.bin
    ${CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32}objcopy  ${BASE}.elf -O srec ${BASE}.srec

    echo "------------------ test rmr_switch2 uart-aarch64 -----------------"
    echo sudo ${SUNXI_FEL} spl sunxi-${SOC}-spl32-ddr3.bin
    echo sudo ${SUNXI_FEL} write ${AARCH32_START_ADDRESS} rmr_switch2.bin
    echo sudo ${SUNXI_FEL} write ${AARCH64_START_ADDRESS} uart-aarch64.bin
    echo sudo ${SUNXI_FEL} exe ${AARCH32_START_ADDRESS}
    echo "------------------------------------------------------------------"
  }

  # prerequisites 
  install_sunxi_tools
  retrieve_spl_aarch32

  # test
  test_aarch32
  test_aarch64
  test_rmr_switch
  test_rmr_switch2
  ```
- rmr_switch.S:

  ```
      .text
      ldr    r1, =0x017000a0               @ MMIO mapped RVBAR[0] register
      ldr    r0, =AARCH64_START_ADDRESS    @ start address, to be replaced
      str    r0, [r1]
      dsb    sy
      isb    sy
      mrc    15, 0, r0, cr12, cr0, 2       @ read RMR register
      orr    r0, r0, #3                    @ request reset in AArch64
      mcr    15, 0, r0, cr12, cr0, 2       @ write RMR register
      isb    sy
  1:  wfi
      b      1b
  ```
- rmr_switch2.S:

  ```
      .text
      ldr    r0, =0x017000a0               @ MMIO mapped RVBAR[0] register
      ldr    r1, =AARCH64_START_ADDRESS    @ start address, to be replaced
      str    r1, [r0]
      dsb    sy
      isb    sy
      mrc    15, 0, r0, cr12, cr0, 2       @ read RMR register
      orr    r0, r0, #3                    @ request reset in AArch64
      mcr    15, 0, r0, cr12, cr0, 2       @ write RMR register
      isb    sy
  1:  wfi
      b      1b
  ```
- uart-aarch32.s:

  ```
                .code 32
                .text
                ldr  r1,=0x01C28000
                ldr  r2,=message
  loop:         ldrb r0, [r2]
                add  r2, r2, #1
                cmp  r0, #0
                beq  completed
                strb r0, [r1]
                b    loop
  completed:    b .
                .data
  message:
                .asciz "*** Hello from aarch32! ***"
                .end
  ```
- - uart-aarch64.s:

    ```
                  .text
                  ldr  x1,=0x01C28000
                  ldr  x2,=message
    loop:         ldrb w0, [x2]
                  add  x2, x2, #1
                  cmp  w0, #0
                  beq  completed
                  strb w0, [x1]
                  b    loop
    completed:    b .
                  .data
    message:
                  .asciz "*** Hello from aarch64! ***"
                  .end
    ```

Once all the files are in the same directory, the test procedure would be:

1. Execute build.sh: You can specify the SOC you are using A64 (default) or H5, and the [aarch32/aarch64 toolchains](https://www.linaro.org/downloads/) in the command-line:

   ```
   CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH64=/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_aarch64-elf/bin/aarch64-elf- CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32=/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-eabi/bin/arm-eabi- ./build.sh
   ```

The output should look like this, (I removed harmless warnings):

```
------------------ test uart-aarch32 -----------------------------
sudo sunxi-tools/sunxi-fel spl sunxi-a64-spl32-ddr3.bin
sudo sunxi-tools/sunxi-fel write 0x40000000 uart-aarch32.bin
sudo sunxi-tools/sunxi-fel exe 0x40000000

------------------ test uart-aarch64 -----------------------------
sudo sunxi-tools/sunxi-fel spl sunxi-a64-spl32-ddr3.bin
sudo sunxi-tools/sunxi-fel write 0x40008000 uart-aarch64.bin
sudo sunxi-tools/sunxi-fel reset64 0x40008000

------------------ test rmr_switch uart-aarch64 ------------------
sudo sunxi-tools/sunxi-fel spl sunxi-a64-spl32-ddr3.bin
sudo sunxi-tools/sunxi-fel write 0x40000000 rmr_switch.bin
sudo sunxi-tools/sunxi-fel write 0x40008000 uart-aarch64.bin
sudo sunxi-tools/sunxi-fel exe 0x40000000

------------------ test rmr_switch2 uart-aarch64 -----------------
sudo sunxi-tools/sunxi-fel spl sunxi-a64-spl32-ddr3.bin
sudo sunxi-tools/sunxi-fel write 0x40000000 rmr_switch2.bin
sudo sunxi-tools/sunxi-fel write 0x40008000 uart-aarch64.bin
sudo sunxi-tools/sunxi-fel exe 0x40000000
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, before entering the `sunxi-fel` commands required for each of the four tests, you need to unplug the Pine64 from its power source and from any USB host receptacle it may be plugged into (USB TTL uart, male-A to male-A USB cable). Reconnect the Pine64 to its power source, then re-plug USB cables.

`lsusb` should now display:

```
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 1f3a:efe8 Onda (unverified) V972 tablet in flashing mode
```

Output on the serial console for the four tests should be:

1. test uart-aarch32 (verifying an aarch32 program runs from 0x40000000):

   ```
   U-Boot SPL 2018.01-00007-gdb0ecc9b42 (Feb 23 2018 - 00:50:52)
   DRAM: 512 MiB
   Trying to boot from FEL
   *** Hello from aarch32! ***
   ```
2. test uart-aarch64 (verifying an aarch64 program runs from 0x40008000):

   ```
   U-Boot SPL 2018.01-00007-gdb0ecc9b42 (Feb 23 2018 - 00:50:52)
   DRAM: 512 MiB
   Trying to boot from FEL
   *** Hello from aarch64! ***
   ```
3. test test rmr_switch uart-aarch64 (running  rmr_switch from 0x40000000, which will switch into aarch64 state and execute uart-aarch64 from 0x40008000):

   ```
   U-Boot SPL 2018.01-00007-gdb0ecc9b42 (Feb 23 2018 - 00:50:52)
   DRAM: 512 MiB
   Trying to boot from FEL
   *** Hello from aarch64! ***
   ```
4. test test rmr_switch2 uart-aarch64 (running  rmr_switch2 from 0x40000000, which will switch into aarch64 state and execute uart-aarch64 from 0x40008000):

   ```
   U-Boot SPL 2018.01-00007-gdb0ecc9b42 (Feb 23 2018 - 00:50:52)
   DRAM: 512 MiB
   Trying to boot from FEL
   *** Hello from aarch64! ***
   ```

It is worth mentioning that those tests can be performed [on Windows](http://linux-sunxi.org/FEL/USBBoot#Using_sunxi-fel_on_Windows) using Linaro mingw32 toolchains, a Windows version of sunxi-fel, and Zadig.

Bottom line, the code you were using seems to be working well, and the rmr_switch2.s code I assembled is the same (I guess) that the one you are using:

```
rmr_switch2.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

40000000 <.text>:
40000000:       e59f0024        ldr     r0, [pc, #36]   ; 4000002c <.text+0x2c>
40000004:       e59f1024        ldr     r1, [pc, #36]   ; 40000030 <.text+0x30>
40000008:       e5801000        str     r1, [r0]
4000000c:       f57ff04f        dsb     sy
40000010:       f57ff06f        isb     sy
40000014:       ee1c0f50        mrc     15, 0, r0, cr12, cr0, {2}
40000018:       e3800003        orr     r0, r0, #3
4000001c:       ee0c0f50        mcr     15, 0, r0, cr12, cr0, {2}
40000020:       f57ff06f        isb     sy
40000024:       e320f003        wfi
40000028:       eafffffd        b       40000024 <.text+0x24>
4000002c:       017000a0        cmneq   r0, r0, lsr #1
40000030:       40008000        andmi   r8, r0, r0
```

The examples were was successfully tested on an H5-based OrangePI PC2. Command-line for running build.sh should be:

```
SOC=h5 CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH64=/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_aarch64-elf/bin/aarch64-elf- CROSS_COMPILE_AARCH32=/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-eabi/bin/arm-eabi- ./build.sh
```

Output for build.sh, and therefore sunxi-fel commands to be executed, will be slightly different, since a different, H5-specific, FEL-capable SPL will have to be used.

I noticed there is a small difference between the code you are using and rmr_switch2 code, but since it comes after the state switch/after wfi, it should not matter I guess - I am assuming the code you assembled was slightly different itself:

Yours (.o):

```
28:   eafffffe        b       28 <_reset+0x28>
```

Mine (.elf):

```
40000028:       eafffffd        b       40000024 <.text+0x24>
```

I hope this help.

Comment: Wow, tremendous work, very interesting. I will have a better look on it. Meanwhile, I was told that writing to RMR from SVC level will not work, only monitor mode can do it. Moreover, following recommendations of other people I have moved to the mainline u-boot with SPL support - managed to reach up to running u-boot with my custom environment. But this requires the SC card. Following the sunxi wiki I was not able to boot in FEL mode, although that would be great for my needs. Thanks for your post!

Comment: No reasons why your Pine64 would not enter FEL mode when there is no SD card and  a male-A to male-A USB cable is being used - not the micro-USB one. Again, make sure to power it up with nothing else connected to your PC. A USB to TTL adapter is sufficient for somewhat powering the Pine64, and preventing a 'clean'power cycling, therefore a triggering of the FEL mode. Believe me, once you use it, you cannot go back when you are testing low-level code. Thank you for your comment - I mainly built over other's work.

Comment: I have added a bit more explanation to my question. First, good catch on the different addresses in `rmr.s` program. But more importantly, this answer helped me to take the FEL approach correctly, which I was not able to do with the sunxi wiki and I gave it up. Now it works and its much more convenient. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Glad to hear FEL is now working for you. Another advantage of the FEL approach is that you should land in aarch64 state at EL3. This is usually useless unless you want to experiment and learn hands off on aarch64, which is my case. Using ATF and mainline u-boot results in u-boot running at EL2.